# LAN world has 2 people in 1?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

So, I have a problem when I join a LAN world with my friends, and whenever I join, I have sort of (to simplify) 2 inventories, this happens to my friends too but not the host of the LAN world (there are 3 of us), I have no idead what triggers it but it seems to be the skins.
When it happens it is either no skin or have skin, (Have skin= inv 1, No skin= inv 2) very confusing. But it gets worse, each inventory is like another person as when we spawn in we are in different places.

Here are the things that might be triggering it.

We use mobile hotspot (maybe requires real wifi)

Host plays alone sometimes.

Comment: Are you playing in offline mode?

Comment: No it says PLAY instead of PLAY OFFLINE

Comment: Are you using the same username?

Comment: Yes, I am indeed using the same

Comment: That would explain it. If two players have the same username on LAN, since LAN technically uses offline mode (I honestly don't fully understand it), you will need to use a different account (or you can change your username manually, and it isn't piracy as you already own the game and it is no different from split-screen).